# ng-repeat with track by and filter and orderBy not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this code.

http://jsfiddle.net/0tgL7u6e/

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.nameFilter = '';
    $scope.contacts = [
        {name: 'GHI'},
        {name: 'DEF'},
        {name: 'ABC'},
        {name: 'JKL'}
    ];
}
```

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div><input type="text" ng-model="nameFilter" placeholder="Search..." /></div>
    <p ng-repeat="contact in contacts track by $index | filter: nameFilter | orderBy: name">{{ contact.name }}</p>
</div>
```

I don't know why the order is not working and why the filter is not working.

At another question, I've read about something that objects can't be filtered or ordered. But I have an array of the objects above. Also, it should work!?

What's the problem?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To use tracking with filters, the track by expression has to be added after the filter.

```
<p ng-repeat="contact in contacts | orderBy: 'name' | filter: nameFilter  track by $index">{{ contact.name }}</p>
```

Here is the working [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/0tgL7u6e/1/)

Comment: No! :D It can't be sooooo easy? But it works :D Thank you very much!

Comment: Of all the similar questions, this is the most apt answer!

Comment: Samething to say for orderBy clause.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the code to the following one

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div><input type="text" ng-model="nameFilter" placeholder="Search..." /></div>
    <p ng-repeat="contact in contacts  | orderBy: name | filter: nameFilter track by $index ">{{ contact.name }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It **does** matter. Without the quotes, it will look for the content of `$scope.name` which does not exist. A jsfiddle of your version: https://jsfiddle.net/saw1uLs9/

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for this example without quotes.