# AngularJS orderBy is not working after new items pushed into array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I have a list of progress notes (collection of simple objects), on this screenshot, first three were in the model, and **the last one was added to the model using push command**:

[image]

In HTML this presenttion is defined like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.data.ProgressNotes|orderBy:'-Date'">
```

reversed sort by Date, most recent are on top.

New object is added to the collection like this:

```
data.ProgressNotes.push({
    Note: progressNote,
    UserName: ctx$.uName,
    Date: new Date()
});
```

Sample model fragment of vm.data.ProgressNotes:

[image]

**Question:** Why new item is not displayed on top, orderBy doesnt work for items added using push ??

Comment: Can you post the data in the model as well? I am wondering if the Date format is different.

Comment: @Anthony C added sample model

Comment: You are using string in the sample model, yet using a date object when you are adding new entry.

Comment: `data.ProgressNotes.push({` How his code is called ? Is this by an `ng-click` or something outside of angular (like `element.addEventListener('click', ...)`). If it's outside of angular loop, you must call `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: ng-submit, or ng-click

Comment: There are almost always two fixes for this mysterious condition:

- It's happening outside of the digest, async probably (I actually figured out a way to repro this without doing anything explicitly async). Use $scope.$apply().

Sometimes that doesn't work, for some very intricate reasons I've read the nitty gritty detail of having to do with model updates and how they trigger digests. If so, you can just try creating an entirely new array, dumping whatever you need into it, and replacing the old one with the new. If necessary (though usually when doing this it isn't), $scope.$apply().

Comment: @AnthonyC is correct. You need to be calling `new Date().toJSON()` when pushing new items on the array to match the data types of the existing models. Otherwise Angular is comparing a string to a Date.

Comment: @Walfrat If the item was being added outside the digest loop, the new item wouldn't be showing up **at all**, instead of in the wrong order.

Comment: @AnthonyC, thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different data type for the Date in the note object. In the model, it is represented as string but when you push a new note to the array, the new note has the Date as date type `Date: new Date()`. When angular does order by with different data types, the comparison is done within the values in the same types and then compares the types themselves alphabetically.
I created a plunker to demonstrate this behavior.

https://plnkr.co/edit/qiKHuRWqI7YR1gJKMvOL?p=preview

Comment: My newly pushed item has the same data type as the one in the initial array, i.e. the JSON date format in string, but still not working.

Comment: Ok, solved, that was because I put the `track by` BEFORE the `orderBy`: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608450/ng-repeat-with-track-by-and-filter-and-orderby-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the type of `Date` property in the sample data is string. You will have to modify the sample data to make the `Date` properties of type Date.

You can do something like this:

```
ProgressNotes.forEach(function(progress_note){
    progress_note.Date = new Date(progress_note.Date);
});
```

So now the sample data will also have Date property of type Date.