# Sort table by column header in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is an array of objects from which I get data to put in the table:

```
$ctrl.myArray = [
            {name: "name1", id: 1, children: ["one", "two"]},
            {name: "name2", id: 2, children: ["two"]},
            {name: "name3", id: 3, children: ["one", "two"]},
            {name: "name4", id: 4, children: ["one"]}
];
```

Putting the data in the table is working fine, the problem comes when I want to add the sorting functionality by columns.

In controller's constructor I added this:

```
this.orderByField = 'name';
this.reverseSort = false;
```

firstly I tried to add the sorting functionality only for the `name` column and this is the code:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='name'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
            Name <span ng-show="orderByField == 'name'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></span>
            </a>
      </th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Children</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.myArray track by $index | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
        <td>
            {{$ctrl.myArray[$index].name}}
        </td>
        <td>{{$ctrl.myArray[$index].id}}</td>
        <td><span ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.myArray[$index].children track by $index">
            {{$ctrl.myArray[$parent.$index].children[$index]}}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is the error message:

> [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received: 0

Don't know why the array is 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-repeat with track by and filter and orderBy not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608450/ng-repeat-with-track-by-and-filter-and-orderby-not-working)

Comment: try different order: `ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.myArray | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort  track by $index"`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey  I tried like that but only the arrow of the header is changing, when I click on it, it changes from `^` to `v` but the data below remains the same. I saw this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608450/ng-repeat-with-track-by-and-filter-and-orderby-not-working) but doesn't solve my problem yet

Comment: @dadsa the problem is in the way you display the data, it doesn't order the original array, it creates a new one. Instead of `{{$ctrl.myArray[$index].name}}` use `{{rows.name}}`, etc.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey you are right! that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue is related to `track by $index`. You have misplaced it.

I have made the plunker for it. Below is the link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/mqA1ofIRUAxal8d8tCr0?p=preview

Comment: OP uses ControllerAs syntax

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, So that is not the issue. I just gave him a solution.  And that is understandable.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya, your solution does the right result but it didn't solve my problem. As @AleksetySolovey said in the comment, the solution to my particular problem was instead of using  `{{$ctrl.myArray[$index].name}}` to use `{{rows.name}}`

Comment: Yes use $ctrl.myArray but don't use $index to display value. Please read ng-repeat from the official site for more clear idea. You are using it in the wrong way.